# How does fragment restores its state

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-savedstate

I have an activity and fragments. The activity is controlling navigation via observing navigation `LiveData` state.

```
sealed class Navigation {
   object Destination1: Navigation()
   object Destination2: Navigation()
}
```

On each change it replaces a fragment in a container (each time a new instance of fragment is created for each destination).

This however does not work when I try to save the state of the fragment. In activity:

```
viewModel.navigation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        replace(R.id.container, fragmentInstance)
        addToBackStack(null)
    }
}
```

I tried to implement the ViewModel SavedStateHandle but the state is not saved. The Handle is empty when I have "don't keep activities" setting ON and I minimize and then maximize the app.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to save state of the Fragment?

How to plug the activity's `savedInstanceState` into the fragments if I create them by observing LiveData? Is the LiveData approach a problem?

Comment: You want to show the last fragment when the user exits the app? Then you should save it in shared preferences I suppose...

Comment: I have found the issue, the parent activity did not call `onCreate` with saved instance state, but with `null`